# Copy or Append first 13 index in Array of Strings to another and sort it - php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to work with array of string in php, its array of images and shuffle the array many times and i need to get the first 13 value from the huge array and place it in another array and then sort the second array of strings. but i am getting two **errors** :

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/index.php on line 46

Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs//index.php on line 50
Array30.png41.png24.png31.png25.png44.png2.png15.png14.png50.png36.png38.png32.png
```

here is my code :

```
   $images = array("1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png","8.png",
        "9.png","10.png","11.png","12.png","13.png","14.png","15.png","16.png","17.png","18.png",
        "19.png","20.png","21.png","22.png","23.png","24.png","25.png","26.png","27.png","28.png",
        "29.png","30.png","31.png","32.png","33.png","34.png","35.png","36.png","37.png","38.png",
        "39.png","40.png","41.png","42.png","43.png","44.png","45.png","46.png","47.png","48.png",
        "49.png","50.png","51.png","52.png"
        );


        shuffle($images);      
        shuffle($images);      
        shuffle($images);  
        shuffle($images);  
        shuffle($images); 

        $playerArraySorted = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {

            $playerArraySorted .= $images[$i];
        }


        ksort($playerArraySorted,2);
         echo "$playerArraySorted";
```

Comment: Looks like you are merging strings in playerArraySorted when you use the .= operator you need to add elements to array using array push http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to push to an array in php, use brackets:

```
$playerArraySorted[] = $images[$i];
```

With `.=` you concatenate strings.

And instead of `echo` in order to check the array, use `var_dump`:

```
var_dump($playerArraySorted);
```

And it seems that your array has no keys, so `ksort` wont work, use `sort` or `usort` with a custom sorting function instead.

Comment: Good but `ksort($playerArraySorted,2)` is not sorting my array !

Comment: thats because your array has no keys, ksort comes from KeySort, use sort instead, or usort with a custom callback function.

Comment: Glad to help you out :)

Comment: One last thing if you may help, when i sort it with this function :            `function my_sort($a,$b)
            {
            if ($a==$b) return 0;
            return ($a<$b)?-1:1;
            }` it returns my images like this half sorted and half not : `17.png 
2.png 
21.png 
25.png 
30.png 
32.png 
37.png 
38.png 
39.png 
40.png 
48.png 
7.png 
9.png `

Comment: I believe that this is because of the names, 17 will come before of 2 because it starts with 1, try using sort($playerArraySorted, SORT_NUMERIC); or natsort($playerArraySorted);. I believe natsort should do the trick.